# How should I do this explicit specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-specialization

Is following design possible?:

```
template <typename T>
class Test{
 public:
  template <typename Z>
  void doSomething();
  //rest of things
 private:
  T obj;
  //some things
};
```

Now if it was possible I'd do some explicit specializations for doSomething so that at the end I'd have some versions like below:

```
void doSomething<int>(){
 //do something
}
void doSomething<double>(){
 //do something
}
...etc
```

which seems impossible I can't find any syntax to do the job then I thought maybe the design should be as it follows so that all template arguments should be passed to template class itself:

```
template <typename T,typename Z>
class Test{
 public:
  void doSomething();
  //rest of things
 private:
  T obj;
  //some things
};
```

Then I tried partial specialization which didn't even compile:

```
template <typename T>
void Test<T,int>::doSomething(){
 //do something
}
template <typename T>
void Test<T,double>::doSomething(){
 //do something
}
...etc
```

I got the following errors for explicit specialization:
error#1:template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list.
error#2:'Container1' :too few template arguments.

Comment: Can't you overload doSomething on a tag and have a catch all with ellipsis or generic template?

Comment: @Tomek_Didn't get what you mean, by the way the focus is on templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to explicitly specialize `doSomething` you have to also explicitly specialize `Test`.

From 14.7.3/18 :

> In an explicit specialization
>   declaration for a member of a class
>   template or a member template that
>   appears in namespace scope, the member
>   template and some of its enclosing
>   class templates may remain
>   unspecialized, **except that the
>   declaration shall not explicitly
>   specialize a class member template if
>   its enclosing class templates are not
>   explicitly specialized as well**.

Comment: As a side note subclass templates can be explicitly specialized without all their enclosing class templates explicitly specialized.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot explicitly specialize a member template unless its enclosing class templates are also explicitly specialized.

So only something like this will work:

```
template<> template<>
void Test<int>::doSomething<int>()
{
}
```

Comment: Smiljanic_"You cannot explicitly specialize a member template unless its enclosing class templates are also explicitly specialized." No that's not right, check my answer.

Comment: @Pooria: Yes it is true, see icecrime's answer for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

you can always make the function inline

```
template <class T>
class Test
{
public:
 template <class Z>
 void doSomething() { cout << "default" << endl; }

 template<>
 void doSomething<int>() { cout << "int" << endl;}
 template<>
 void doSomething<double>() { cout << "double" << endl; }
private:
 T obj;
};
```

Comment: By the way this gets compiled on visual C++ 2008 due to some bug I guess!!  ;) .

Comment: it compiled for me also in visual C++ 2010, thats why i wrote it. It also works if you run it in visual C++ 2010, so I do not deserve -1:)

Comment: The funny thing at least with VC++ 2008 is, no problem compiling when specializing with inline definitions, but for specializations with not-inline definitions once there's more than one version it doesn't get compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is picky. I suppose you can't do it, read [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a bug in g++ but this compiles and produce what I expect.

```
#include<typeinfo>
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    template<typename Z>
    void doSomething();

private:
    T obj;
};

template<typename T>
template<typename Z>
void Test<T>::doSomething()
{
    Z val;
    std::cout << __func__ << ": type " << typeid(val).name() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test<double> a;
    a.doSomething<int>();
    a.doSomething<double>();
}
```

Comment: That's not explicit specialization, so no bug at all.

Comment: Yes it just defining the templated member funćtion. Tried Nikola Smiljanić and it works with g++.

Answer (score -2):

icecrime posted a temporary answer and it gets compiled due to some bug probably by visual C++ 2008:

```
template <typename T>
class Test{
 public:
  template <typename Z>
  void doSomething();
  //rest of things
 private:
  T obj;
  //some things
};
template <>
template <typename T>
void Test<T>::doSomething<int>(){
 //do something
}
```

Check his current answer though.
The funny thing at least with VC++ 2008 is, no problem compiling when specializing with inline definitions, but for specializations with not-inline definitions once there's more than one version it doesn't get compiled successfully.

Comment: On my g++ version it doesn't compile.

Comment: why the hell downvote when it gets compiled perfectly on visual C++ 2008?

Comment: This one definitely shouldn't work. And in fact it doesn't in MSVC10.

Comment: It's not valid C++, if it compiles for you it is a compiler extension or a bug (depending on how you look at things).